# jquery Animate - Hiding a div upon click of an 'x' svg

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate

Please can someone tell me why my code isn't working, I want to hide the 'adtest' div upon clicking the 'svg' with a smooth animation. Here is my relevant code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

function byeFooter(){
 $("#adtest").animate({ bottom: -100 })
   .fadeOut();
} 2000;
$("#svgme").on("click", byeFooter);



</script>

   <footer class="footer">
       <div id="adtest">
           <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">
               <div id="clickme">
                   <img id="img-1" src="Topshop3.png">
                   <img id="img-2" src="Topshop2.png">
                   <img id="img-2" src="Topshop1.png">
               </div>
           </a>
           <svg id = "svgme" height="23" width="23">
               <circle cx="14" cy="14" r="7" stroke="gray" stroke-width="1.8" fill="lightgray" />
               <line x1="9" y1="9" x2="19" y2="19" style="stroke:rgb(128,128,128);stroke-width:1.5" />
               <line x1="19" y1="9" x2="9" y2="19" style="stroke:rgb(128,128,128);stroke-width:1.5" /></svg>
       </div>
       <div id="adback"></div>
   </footer>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try placing `script` below `footer`

Comment: well, that was an easy fix. Brilliant thank you!!